# Strange behavior on git mac client

Tags: git

when I push from a local branch using:
**git push** or **git push origin develop** command

the server also returns that:

```
To git.coding.net:maydaygjw/research-ui.git
 ! [rejected]        develop -> refs/for/develop (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.coding.net:maydaygjw/research-ui.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

While using `git push origin develop:develop` which works fine, but I actually pulled at every time

And which develop branch tracked the remote develop branch in the local config:

```
❯ git branch -vv
* develop d48ec5f [origin/develop] fix
  master  a390f07 [origin/master: ahead 1] fix
```

But on windows, all works fine, I tried different git mac clients but all works as this, is this a bug for mac os?

Comment: Check line endings...

Comment: Specifically: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/